# Is there a way to update a Cors policy after startup?

Tags: cors, .net-6.0

I have an API with a CORS policy that sets allowed origins based on values in a database. (it's for a white labelled app that users can configure their own domains for).

In `Startup.cs` I'm currently adding the CORS policy as normal, accept the list of Allowed Origins is looked up from the database.

I was looking for a way to update that CORS policy at run time without restarting the API, perhaps on a timer, or perhaps after a specific POST API request.

Does anybody know if this is possible? I can't seem to find much about this particular scenario. I am using .Net 6.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do that? How frequent would those updates be? Is restarting the server too costly? Bear in mind that CORS, as a mechanism for relaxing the SOP, is security-critical; therefore, you ideally want changes to your CORS policy to be reviewed before they go live.

Comment: Some CORS libraries, whether intentionally or inadvertently, allow you to update a CORS middleware after the fact; see, for instance, https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#11-guarantee-configuration-immutability. I'm not familiar enough with .NET to have a definite answer for you. That said, even if you could, you probably have to worry about synchronisation: some request may cause an invocation of the CORS middleware at the exact same time you're updating its policy.

Comment: @jub0bs the new origins would be added by us, but having to restart the API every time would be too costly in terms of up-time. A lot of users will be accessing the API and can be running time critical or sensitive processes that we don't want to interrupt. Waiting until the next scheduled maintenance to restart wouldn't be ideal either as it would hold up onboarding of new clients.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for adding more context. There's a property named [`IsOriginAllowed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicy.isoriginallowed?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that accepts a function. Seems to be right up your alley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up doing something similar to this tutorial, using the `CorsPolicyAccessor` as inspiration.

https://dzone.com/articles/reconfiguring-cors-policy-in-aspnet-core-at-runtim

First I created a policy provider class that is registered as a hosted service and inherits the `BackgroundService` class. This runs a timer that refreshes my CORS origins after a period of time.

```cs
public class CorsPolicyProvider : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly CorsOptions options;
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration;

    public CorsPolicyProvider(IOptions<CorsOptions> options, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.options = options.Value;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await CreatePolicy();

        var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            await UpdatePolicy();
        }
    }

    private async Task CreatePolicy()
    {
        var allowedOrigins = new List<string>();

        // get static origins from appsettings.json
        configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Bind(allowedOrigins);
        
        var configurableOrigins = await GetConfigurableOrigins()
        allowedOrigins.AddRange(configurableOrigins);

        options.AddPolicy("AllowedSpecificOrigins", policy => policy.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins.ToArray()).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
    }

    private async Task UpdatePolicy()
    {
        var origins = await GetConfigurableOrigins();
        var policy = options.GetPolicy("AllowedSpecificOrigins");

        // filter all origins to ones that aren't already in the policy
        foreach (var origin in origins.Where(x => !policy.Origins.Any(y => y == x)))
        {
            policy.Origins.Add(origin);
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<string>> GetConfigurableOrigins()
    {
        // get configurable origins from other source (database/config file, etc.)
    }
}
```

And then register it as a Hosted Service in `Startup.cs` in place of the existing `.AddPolicy` method (they conflicted for me).

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /* ... */
    services.AddHostedService<CorsPolicyProvider>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    /* ... */
    app.UserCors("AllowedSpecificOrigins");
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I'm worried by the apparent lack of synchronisation in the code from the article you link to. Isn't .NET' server concurrent? Besides, you better make sure that those *add* and *remove* endpoints are behind authorisation or protected by a firewall. If malicious actors can alter your CORS policy at will, you're in trouble.

Comment: In fact, the author concedes the following: _there is a small risk of a race involved_.

Comment: I didn't copy the articles implementation, but used it as inspiration. Mainly the parts regarding the `CorsPolicyAccessor`. I'll update my answer with my implementation so it can hopefully help someone else.